# Copy AAR after assembleDebug

Tags: android, gradle

Can someone please tell my why this does nothing? I've messed with it for two days. The text is never printed, copyAAR is never run. Should be so simple but obviously I'm missing something. This is a project with a main "app" and one module called "MY_Library". This code is in the build.gradle file for My_Library. THANKS!

```
task copyAAR(dependsOn:'assembleDebug') << {
    println "++++++ AAR COPIED ++++++: "
}
```

Also tried:

```
afterEvaluate {
    copyAAR.dependsOn ':MY_Library:assembleDebug'
}

task copyAAR() << {
    println "++++++ AAR COPIED ++++++: "
}
```

Executing tasks: [:MY_Library:assembleDebug]

Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
    at build_bxaa81mwx93hvs7njvdit9vtz$_run_closure1.doCall(C:\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\MY_Library\build.gradle:19)
    (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
:MY_Library:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:MY_Library:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:MY_Library:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:MY_Library:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:MY_Library:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
23 actionable tasks: 23 up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only way I got it to work was:

```
afterEvaluate {
   assembleDebug.finalizedBy(copyAAR)
}
```

Why did the other way not work?!?!?